# Feedback on app

Tags: discussion, android-app

I have some generic feedback:

- "sign in with other OpenID" page could do with something saying "loading", preferrably in the ActionBar. Also the login buttons should be listed vertically instead of horizontal.
- Notifications should work like another sliding drawer. Google said to basically copy the Google donation app for this
- Can you replace Pull to Refresh with https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh
- I would reconmend changing some of the app branding based on the site, for example the ActionBar colour
- I don't know if it's implemented, but GCM push for notifications would be nice (along with expanded notifications for these)

Overall, it feels fairly nice

Comment: Just as a heads-up, GCM push notifications already exist in the app. Regarding the pull to refresh suggestion, I can see where you're coming from seeing that it's the actual successor of the one we're using in our app but I don't think we'll be integrating a preview build library at the moment.

Comment: I don't like the loading screen. Can you get rid of that?

Comment: Also can you remove the modal ProgressDialog's?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the feedback! Most of these things are on our radar:

1. Redesigning the "Sign in with OpenID" path is planned.
2. Notifications will work like the drawer, we just haven't gotten to it yet.
3. We're thinking about changing the Pull to Refresh library, but it's low priority since what we have works for now
4. We've redesigned the feed to make the sites more visible. I'm not sure we want to change the overall look-and-feel for each site in the app, so probably no actionbar color changes.
5. GCM push notifications should be working for anything that shows up in your inbox. If you're not getting them, it's a bug.